# Retrieve the initial Options passed to the Form.Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there a way to retrieve the initial options passed to the `FormBuilder` for the creation of the form? I know `FormConfigInterface` has method `getOptions()`, but I have used that and got the resolved options of the form instead, e.g: after being normalized.
So how can I get the original options passed by the user?

```
//by options, I mean the $options passed here
$formFactory->create('form_name', 'form_type', $options);
```

then I want to access $options later in and `EventListener` registered to this form:

```
//.. in a form EventListener e.g: on preSubmit
$form = $event->getForm();
$options = $form-> ? //this is where I want to get $options that was passed above during the form's creation.
```

Comment: I don't know the use case but you could also store the initial options in a session.

Comment: @gp_sflover What do you mean by "original options passed by the user"?

Comment: @acontell Maybe I don't well understood the question but I think @user2268997 wants retrieve these "initial options" after `$form->handleRequest($request)`.

Comment: added details to question

Comment: your question is not clear, are you passing some custom data to form that you want to use? What do you mean by `So how can I get the original options passed by the user? `

Comment: @Baig, explained further.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve it with the current Form Component implementation is quite complicated, you'd need replicate the behavior of `ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy` to be able to get the "passed options" after they are resolved.

I suggest you go back to the trivial method: defines a custom form option to pass the initial options.

```
class CustomFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('initial_options', $options['initial']);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            // do something with:
            $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getAttribute('initial_options');
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'initial' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

So, you'd pass the "initial" option also to the form type options. Something like this:

```
$options['initial'] = $options;
$formFactory->create('form_name', CustomFormType::class, $options);
```

Comment: I can't add an option like that, it has to work seamlessly, i.e: without the user (programmer) changing anything.

Comment: Can you define "without the user (programmer) changing anything"? Your question no mention nothing about :/ what are the limitations?

Answer (score -1):

Inside your form class, you can add the following attribute and getter :

```
private $defaultOptions;

public function getDefaultOptions() {
   return $this->defaultOptions;
}
```

And, in your `buildForm` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->defaultOptions = $options;
    //...
}
```

Finally, in your EventListener :

```
//.. in a form EventListener e.g: on preSubmit
$form = $event->getForm();
$options = $form->getDefaultOptions();
```

Comment: Why a downvote ? Not what is asked ? Needs some more explanations ?

Comment: The `buildForm` gives the resolved options and the question says passed/initial options only.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was not yet resolved here. The answer from @yceruto is better then